# How to set up an online chat without javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, long-polling

I stumbled upon a rather strange site the other day : https://harmless.herokuapp.com/main

It is an online mini chat that **does not use javascript** on the client side, and yet it allows you to display your messages and those of others, in real time.

While trying to document myself I came across the term **"Long Polling"** but all the sources I could look at used javascript to implement it.

I guess the **forever loading page** is something to do with it.
From what I understand, if a valid XMLHttpRequest is not returned, then the client-side browser never closes the connection with the server and keeps trying to receive data.
I tried the code below but it didn't work : [How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/how-do-i-implement-basic-long-polling)

```php
<?php

if(rand(1,3) == 1){
    /* Fake an error */
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    die();
}

/* Send a string after a random number of seconds (2-10) */
sleep(rand(2,10));
echo("Hi! Have a random number: " . rand(1,10));

?>
```

**In short, I wanted to understand how a site could update the data received and send it back to the user in real time without using client-side javascript.**

### **EDIT :**

Here is the answer : [github.com/kkuchta/css-only-chat](https://github.com/kkuchta/css-only-chat)

Thank you to **Flux** for his find!

Comment: Try PHP sockets, long polling will make your server unable to handle other requests, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/how-do-i-implement-basic-long-polling

Comment: While it's probably _technically_ possible, it will be ugly to write, ugly to look at, and perform like trash. Use Javascript.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/kkuchta/css-only-chat

Comment: omg after 2 years I finally understood how it was possible and it's all thanks to you. Thank you so much!!!